# TestFlight Issue With Invitation

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I have successfully invited my internal testers to test my 2nd build, and they have both received the invite email. The problem is that when they click on the invite, when they are taken into TestFlight they get a message saying the app is not available. If you have any experience with this or know how to fix this please let me know. I think the pictures below will be very helpful in finding my problem.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Could you have possibly turned off beta testing somehow after you sent the invites?  Could you try turning beta testing on and off again?

Comment: @milesper that did the trick! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as an answer and give you reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure beta testing is turned on, or try turning it off and on again.

Comment: Is the user opening the email in mail and clicking the link from there?

Comment: Yep, the user did open the email and click on that link.

Comment: Are they internal or external?

Answer (score 2):

The user must click on the invite on their device **using the Apple mail app**. They cannot use Gmail, for example, to successfully make the build appear in Apple's TestFlight app.